# YII Report Sales Missing Array

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i have problem with array looping.

i have 2 table. employee and sales. table structure like this.

```
car=> select id,fullname,dealer_id from sc_employee where dealer_id=1;
 id |     fullname      | dealer_id 
----+-------------------+-----------
  1 | James Butt        |         1
  2 | Josephine Darakjy |         1
  3 | Art Venere        |         1
  4 | Lenna Paprocki    |         1
(4 rows)


car=> select * from sc_recsales where dealer_senderid='831081551';
 id  | vehicle_typeid | spk_num  |     vin_num      | retail_date | bpk_num  | sc_id | notes |   price   | dealer_senderid 
-----+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------+----------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------------
 515 |            120 | CAR00003 | H4TB2H26CC000002 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00003 |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 516 |            120 | CAR00004 | H4TB2H26CC000003 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00004 |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 518 |            120 | CAR00006 | H4TB2H26CC000005 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00006 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 519 |            120 | CAR00007 | H4TB2H26CC000006 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00007 |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 520 |            120 | CAR00008 | H4TB2H26CC000007 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00008 |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 521 |            120 | CAR00009 | H4TB2H26CC000008 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00009 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 522 |            120 | CAR00010 | H4TB2H26CC000009 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00010 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 524 |            120 | CAR00012 | H4TB2H26CC000011 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00012 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 525 |            120 | CAR00013 | H4TB2H26CC000012 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00013 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 526 |            120 | CAR00014 | H4TB2H26CC000013 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00014 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 527 |            120 | CAR00015 | H4TB2H26CC000014 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00015 |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 528 |            120 | CAR00016 | H4TB2H26CC000015 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00016 |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 530 |            120 | CAR00018 | H4XZ2D26CC000002 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00018 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 531 |            120 | CAR00019 | H4XZ2D26CC000003 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00019 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 532 |            120 | CAR00020 | H4XZ2D26CC000004 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00020 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 533 |            120 | CAR00021 | H4XZ2D26CC000005 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00021 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 535 |            120 | CAR00023 | H4XZ2D26CC000007 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00023 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 536 |            120 | CAR00024 | H4XZ2D26CC000008 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00024 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 537 |            120 | CAR00025 | H4XZ2D26CC000009 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00025 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 538 |            120 | CAR00026 | H4AA5D26CC000001 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00026 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 539 |            120 | CAR00027 | H4AA5D26CC000002 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00027 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 541 |            120 | CAR00029 | H4AA5D26CC000004 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00029 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 542 |            120 | CAR00030 | H4AA5D26CC000005 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00030 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 543 |            120 | CAR00031 | H4AA5D26CC000006 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00031 |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 544 |            120 | CAR00032 | H4AA5D26CC000007 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00032 |     4 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 545 |            120 | CAR00033 | H4AA5D26CC000008 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00033 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 547 |            120 | CAR00035 | H4AA5D26CC000010 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00035 |     3 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 514 |            120 | CAR00002 | H4TB2H26CC000001 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00002 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 513 |            120 | CAR00001 | H4TB2H26CC000000 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00001 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 517 |            120 | CAR00005 | H4TB2H26CC000004 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00005 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 523 |            120 | CAR00011 | H4TB2H26CC000010 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00011 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 529 |            120 | CAR00017 | H4XZ2D26CC000001 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00017 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 534 |            120 | CAR00022 | H4XZ2D26CC000006 | 2015-12-26  | CAR00022 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 540 |            120 | CAR00028 | H4AA5D26CC000003 | 2016-01-15  | CAR00028 |     1 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
 546 |            120 | CAR00034 | H4AA5D26CC000009 | 2015-11-05  | CAR00034 |     2 |       | 500000000 | 831081551
```

in model
models/ScRecsales.php

```
    public static function getTest2($dealer) {

            $salesCount = ScRecsales::find()
                                ->select(['*'])
                                ->where("dealer_senderid ='$dealer'")
                                ->all();
            return $salesCount;
    }

    public static function getStaff($dealer) {

            $staff = ScEmployee::find()
                                ->select(['*'])
                                ->where('dealer_id = '.$dealer)
                                ->all();
            return $staff;
    }

and in my controller 

   public function actionTest() {
//      $dealer = $_GET['dealer_id'];
        $dealer = 831081551;

        $sales = ScRecsales::getTest2($dealer);
        $salesman = ScRecsales::getStaff(1);

        return $this->render('report', [
            'sales' => $sales,
            'salesman'=>$salesman
        ]);
    }

and in my view 

<?php

$temp = array();

$year = array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08' , '09', '10', '11', '12');
foreach ($salesman as $key => $man) {
    foreach ($sales as $sl => $value) {

        if ($key == $value['sc_id']) {

            $retail_date = $value['retail_date'];
            $timestamp = strtotime($retail_date);
            $month = date("m", $timestamp);

            if (!empty($temp[$key][$month])) {
                $temp[$key][$month]++;
            } else {
                $temp[$key][$month] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

$finalRes = array();

foreach ($temp as $sales => $man) {
    foreach ($year as $key => $val) {
        $finalRes[$sales][$val] = (!empty($man[$val])) ? $man[$val] : 0;
    }
}
//die(print_r($finalRes));

echo '<table width="100%" border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>&nbsp;</th>';
echo '<th>January</th>';
echo '<th>February</th>';
echo '<th>March</th>';
echo '<th>April</th>';
echo '<th>May</th>';
echo '<th>June</th>';
echo '<th>July</th>';
echo '<th>August</th>';
echo '<th>September</th>';
echo '<th>October</th>';
echo '<th>November</th>';
echo '<th>December</th>';
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($finalRes as $key => $val) {
//die(print_r($salesman[$key]));
//print_r($salesman[$key]);
echo '<tr>';
echo ' <td>'.$salesman[$key]['fullname'].'</td>';
foreach ($val as $v) {
echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
 }
echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

everything works, but an employee with first array is not printed on the report.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view. u can change this

```
if ($man['id'] == $value['sc_id']) {

    $retail_date = $value['retail_date'];
    $timestamp = strtotime($retail_date);
    $month = date("m", $timestamp);

    if (!empty($temp[$key][$month])) {
        $temp[$key][$month]++;
    } else {
        $temp[$key][$month] = 1;
    }
}
```